# Does the Firebase datasnapshot contain data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does the datasnapshot from Firebase rtdb download the data every time?

I mean to ask if I don't call `.val()` but simply check `.hasChildren()` will the size my data in database (which would have been accessible by calling `.val()` be counted towards my downloaded quota?

Answer (score 2):

A `DataSnapshot` contains a snapshot of the data at the moment it was taken. It always contains this data, even before you actually read its value or call any other methods on it.

Comment: So, you mean, it will be counted against my downloaded data

Comment: Since the snapshot contains your data, the data will indeed be downloaded and thus count against your quota/be charged.

Comment: Ok. This information is very important for me to structure my d.b.

Comment: Your question seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), describing a solution and then asking about that. Since that's all you shared, I can only answer that question and explain how the system works (which I did above). If you're trying to solve a problem, it's typically best to also frame that problem in your question. For example: if you want to find out the cheapest way to check if a specific child node exists without downloading all data in that node, that might take a very different solution than what you currently asked about.